# Combining multiple CSV files to single CSV file

Tags: excel, vbscript

Below is the code which is used to copy all the rows from one CSV file and paste it in another CSV file.

```
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
  Set combineCSV = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("e:\combineCSV.csv")

  nextrow = combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(11).Row+1

  xlWkb.Activate
  xlWkb.WorkSheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

  combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Cells(nextrow+1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)

  xlWkb.Close  

  combineCSV.Saved = True
  combineCSV.close
```

Up to copying it works fine, but using the `PasteSpecial` method is raising an error:

> PasteSpecial method of range class failed.

Comment: Did you define `xlPasteAll`?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner xlPasteAll is vbscript parameter, which paste values from clipboard. it need not be defined.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner removing xlPasteAll - doesn't display any error, but rows are not copied another csv file, did the save file is somehow problem?

Comment: It needs to be defined if your VBScript code runs from c/wscript.exe (as opposed to VBA code running in Excel).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner oh ok. so defining as Dim xlPasteAll will be fine right?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Defined as Const xlPasteAll = -4104. now no error. but still the rows are not copied??

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner finally it worked. After defining xlPasteAll=-4104 and adding line combineCSV.Save. It worked. Thanks a lot for your help.